# I want to prove that there are no complex numbers that satisfy the following equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, complex-numbers, proof-writing

I introduce the following equation: $$( a + b )^2 = a^2 + b^2$$ I know that any number has an imaginary part and a real one, meaning: $$a = k_1  i + c_1$$ $$b = k_2  i + c_2$$ Thus : $$ ( k_1  i + c_1 )(k_2  i + c_2 ) = ( k_1  i + c_1 )^2 + ( k_2  i + c_2 )^2$$ $$k_1  i \cdot i  k_2 + k_1  i \cdot  c_2 + k_2  i\cdot   c_1 + c_1  c_2$$ I arrive at this final result : $$\frac{k_1  k_2}{c_1  c_2} \left(\frac{c_2}{k_2} + \frac{c_1}{k_1}\right) = i$$ This result is absurd, since the sum of any real numbers is a real number. There's no "non-zero" complex number that satisfies the first equation.

Comment: What if $a=0$ or $b=0$? If none of them are zero then the result is clear, since $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$. No need to split them into real and imaginary parts for this.

Comment: Extending the comment of @Mark, just to be clear, in Complex Analysis, similar to Real Analysis, given complex numbers $~z_1, z_2,~$ you have that $$z_1 \times z_2 = 0 \iff [ ~(z_1 = 0) \vee (z_2 = 0) ~].$$  Note that in Complex Analysis, with $~z = x + iy ~: ~x,y \in \Bbb{R},~$ you have that $$z = 0 \iff  [ ~(x = 0) \wedge (y = 0) ~].$$

Comment: to be precise, ALL real numbers are Complex numbers, You should rather use ".....no purely imaginary numbers......" in the question

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi. No nonzero complex numbers, you mean?

Comment: Please explain me one thing. In 1st line,you have written $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$ ,but after writing $a$ and $b$ as a complex number,you have written that $ab=a^2+b^2$.I don't understand it.

Comment: @TedShifrin,yes,I was naive to assume OP's calculation correct, It is flawed anyways, now that you have pointed out, The question makes sense only by using "..........No nonzero complex number........"